# Проверка по типу - переменная или число

Tags: c#

Всем здравствуйте! Такой вот вопрос: возможно ли создать такое условие, которое смогло бы определить - элемент массива простое число или же оно является переменной. Для наглядности приведу массив:

```
int x = 2;
int y = 5;
int z = 2;

int[,] VirtualMapMassive =
{
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,2,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,2,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,z,z,3,3,3,3,z,y,3,z,y,3,3,y,y,3,3,3,3,1},
    {1,1,x,y,4,4,4,4,x,y,4,z,y,4,4,z,y,4,4,0,4,1},
    {1,1,2,5,1,1,1,1,2,5,1,1,1,1,1,2,5,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,0,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,2,5,1,1,1,1,2,5,1,1,1,1,1,2,5,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,z,z,3,3,3,3,z,y,3,3,3,3,3,z,y,3,3,y,y,1},
    {1,1,x,y,4,4,4,4,z,y,4,4,4,4,4,z,y,4,4,z,y,1},
    {1,1,2,5,1,1,1,1,2,5,1,1,1,1,1,2,5,1,1,2,5,1},
    {1,1,0,5,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,5,1,1,0,5,1},
    {1,1,2,5,1,1,1,1,2,5,1,1,1,1,1,2,5,1,1,2,5,1},
    {1,3,z,y,3,3,3,3,z,y,3,3,3,3,3,z,y,0,3,z,y,1},
    {1,4,x,y,4,4,4,4,z,y,4,4,4,4,4,z,y,4,4,z,y,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,5,1,1,1,1,1,2,0,1,1,2,5,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,5,1,1,1,1,1,2,5,1,1,2,5,1},
    {1,3,z,y,3,3,0,3,z,y,3,3,0,3,3,z,y,3,3,z,y,1},
    {1,4,x,y,4,4,4,4,z,y,4,4,4,4,4,z,y,4,4,z,y,1},
    {1,1,2,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,5,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,2,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,5,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
};
```

*Условно:

```
foreach (x in VirtualMapMassive)
{
    if (x is Digit)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(1);
    }

    if (x is Variable)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(2);
    }

    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: В показанном виде это невозможно. В массиве будут храниться _значения_, а не ссылки на переменные.

Comment: Нет, не возможно. `int` - значимый тип, а значит есть только значение.

Comment: Как вариант, дать переменным значения, которых нет у констант, например добавить 100 к каждой, тогда можно будет по значению определить.

Comment: Сделать отдельный класс для этих штук и помещать туда именно экземпляры класса.